# Formatação/Pontuação de valores em reais

Tags: jquery

Eu tenho uma comparação de valores para verificar se é possível efetuar um saque ou não.

Estou com problemas pra formatar os valores e fazer esse comparativo.

Veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E no console esta me trazendo formatado desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, sempre que for validar se o valor a sacar é menor que o saldo disponível, ele entra na condição que retorna que o valor para o saque é maior que o valor disponível, por causa da formatação/pontuação.

Segue código:

```
 if (parseFloat($("#txtVlrSacar").val().replace(",", ".")) > parseFloat($("#lblSaldo").text().replace(",", "."))) {
                        LimparSaque();
                        swal("", "Valor para saque maior do que valor disponível!", "warning");
                        return;
                    }
```

Comment: `parseFloat($("#lblSaldo").text()` não seria `parseFloat($("#lblSaldo").val()`

Comment: por algum motivo fica retornando com NaN se eu alterar pra val()

Comment: Tenta substituir o ponto por vazio e vírgula por ponto `$("#lblSaldo").text().replace('.","").replace(",", ".")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dei uma organizada para que facilite o entendimento e melhore a manutenção.

Segue o código:

```
var txtVlrSacar = $("#txtVlrSacar").val();
var txtSaldo = $("#lblSaldo").text();

//Retira todas as ocorrências de pontos. Em seguida transforma as vírgulas existentes em ponto para que seja possível a conversão para float.
var txtVlrSacarFormatado = txtVlrSacar.replace(/\./g, '').replace(",",".");
var txtSaldoFormatado = txtSaldo.replace(/\./g, '').replace(",",".");

var numVlrSacar = parseFloat(txtVlrSacarFormatado);
var numSaldo = parseFloat(txtSaldoFormatado);

if (numVlrSacar > numSaldo) {
    LimparSaque();
    swal("", "Valor para saque maior do que valor disponível!", "warning");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Igor, você precisa primeiro substituir o ponto "." por nada. Primeiro deve-se formatar o milhar, para depois formatar o decimal.

```
var saldo = parseFloat($("#lblSaldo").text().replace('.","").replace(",", ".");
var valorSacar = parseFloat($("#txtVlrSacar").text().replace('.","").replace(",", ".");

if (valorSacar > saldo) {
    LimparSaque();
    swal("", "Valor para saque maior do que valor disponível!", "warning");
    return;
}
```